# Actualizar UI cada 1 segundo solo actualiza cada 4? Android Studio

Tags: java, android, timer

Estoy trabajando en Android Studio y tengo el siguiente problema y no sé por qué sucede:
Mi código toma la hora unix actual en milisegundos, divide la hora unix por 1000 para extraer los segundos, le resta una fecha en unix en segundos y muestra el resultado. Hice un timer que lo realiza cada un segundo, pero en la UI el número sólo se actualiza cada ~4 segundos en vez de cada un segundo como en la consola.

Pensé que quizás tiene que ver con android, quizás tiene un límite de actualización de UI por segundo? Dejo el código más abajo:

```
        Timer EachSec = new Timer();            //Creates a timer with 1s delay
    TimerTask Refresh = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread( new TimerTask(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    long AnDate = 1476650909;       //October 16th 2016, 5:48PM in seconds Unix
                    TextView SecondsText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SecondsText);   //links TextViewers with objects
                    TextView MinutesText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MinutesText);   //links TextViewers with objects
                    TextView HoursText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HoursText);       //links TextViewers with objects
                    TextView DaysText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DaysText);         //links TextViewers with objects
                    TextView MonthText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.MonthText);
                    long SecondsTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000 - AnDate;        //Gets current time in milliseconds, pass it to seconds and subtracts AnDate, now having elapsed time in s
                    float MinutesTime = SecondsTime/60;     //pass it to minutes
                    float HoursTime = MinutesTime/60;       //pass it to hours
                    float DaysTime = HoursTime/24;          //pass it to days
                    float MonthTime = DaysTime/30;          //pass it to roughly months
                    String SecSt = String.valueOf(Math.round(SecondsTime)) + " " + getString(R.string.secondsSTR);      //transforms seconds to string and concatenates with the word and saves it into a string variable
                    String MinSt = String.valueOf(Math.round(MinutesTime)) + " " + getString(R.string.minutes);         //transforms minutes to string and concatenates with the word and saves it into a string variable
                    String HourSt = String.valueOf(Math.round(HoursTime)) + " "+  getString(R.string.hours);             //transforms hours to string and concatenates with the word and saves it into a string variable
                    String DaySt = String.valueOf(Math.round(DaysTime)) + " " + getString(R.string.days);                //transforms days to string and concatenates with the word and saves it into a string variable
                    String MonSt = String.valueOf(Math.round(MonthTime)) + " " + getString(R.string.months);
                    SecondsText.setText(SecSt);         //sets TextView text to concatenated string
                    MinutesText.setText(MinSt);         //sets TextView text to concatenated string
                    HoursText.setText(HourSt);          //sets TextView text to concatenated string
                    DaysText.setText(DaySt);            //sets TextView text to concatenated string
                    MonthText.setText(MonSt);           //sets TextView text to concatenated string
                    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000 - AnDate);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    EachSec.schedule(Refresh, 0, 1000);     //1 second
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer el problema está en que antes de mostrarlo, le apliqué `Math.round(SeconsTime)` por lo que el valor es el mismo por aproximadamente 4 segundos. Lo descubrí tras probar poniendo `System.out.println(Math.round(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000 - AnDate));` y darme cuenta que el valor es el mismo por un tiempo.